# Wifi not connecting depending on power supply

Tags: wifi, power-supply, touchscreen

I am using a RPI 3 B+ with a [Touchscreen](https://www.sunfounder.com/10-1-touch-screen-display-2069.html). It worked for almost a year but since 2 weeks the pi is no longer connecting to wifi. The adapter is there, I can even select my wifi, enter my password but then nothing happens.

Using a wifi dongle, I was able to connect to my wifi without issues.

I swtiched out the pi and the issue is the same.

The pi is usually powered by the Touchscreen controller-board. So I tried powering the pi from an external source. That did the trick, wifi is working as normal.

While testing I noticed that there is a short low voltage warning while booting (yellow lightning bolt).

The touchscreen's power supply must be causing an issue while booting, rendering the on-board wifi adapter useless.

**Would it be possible to delay the initialisation of the wifi adapter to some time after the boot when there is no high load on the power supply?**

**How can I troubleshoot the issue further and find out why the adapter is not connecting?**

**Why are wifi dongles working and the on-board wifi isn't?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stubled upon this hackaday post: https://hackaday.com/2019/11/28/raspberry-pi-4-hdmi-is-jamming-its-own-wifi/

I tried replacing the HDMI cable and that did the trick. Still strange that it worked for so long.